# Incrementing the numeric part of an alphanumeric criteria to search multiple columns and print records with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I should note that there are related solutions to my question online but I've been unable to implement them into my own situation.

We have an .mdb database of all the products that we make. I've managed to take two criteria (Order type and Box), and print all records containing those two criteria to Excel. What I need in addition to that now is to print 30 boxes in one go as a basis for a bigger template. The labeling of these boxes usually increment (e.g. P1, P2...P30), and I'm struggling to see how I can increment the numeric portion of it to fit it into my code. Ideally, I'd like for the user to input the first and last box numbers in excel to represent the entire range (P1 and P30) and use those two values.

```
Sub Dan()
    Dim order As String
    Dim title As String        'initialize title
    Dim palette As String      'intialize comment
    Dim finalpalette As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer    'initialize bottom-most row
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Cntr As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer

    'Clears the contents of the last macro run
    With Sheets("ALL.txt")
       .Range(.Cells(6, 2), .Cells(725, 8)).ClearContents 'equates to (D2:F26)/          row, column ;Erase Columns for next macro
    End With

    title = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value
    palette = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 3 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = title And Cells(i, 2) = palette Then
            Cells(i, 5).Copy 'Copy ID
            Sheets("ALL.txt").Range("B734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

            Range(Cells(i, 11), Cells(i, 14)).Copy
            Sheets("ALL.txt").Range("C734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

            Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 10)).Copy
            Sheets("ALL.txt").Range("G734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial        
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The variable I'm looking to adjust is 'palette'. I originally used it to match records to one Box (P1). What I need is to able to match records from 30 boxes (P1 to P30) in the loop. The variable 'palette' is just taking the static value of whatever is in cell B2 at the moment. I'm thinking there should be some way to type the first and last box into two cells  to establish a range for the macro to iterate, or to write all the box numbers into a column and have 'palette' move down a cell each loop to take in a new Box value.

In an attempt to grab data from a column that has all 30 boxes written into 30 cells, I tried the following line of code

```
        End If
palette = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Offset(, 1)
Next i
```

but it does not seem to be grabbing any value. It should be grabbing values from cells B2 to B31.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I changed (still no clue as to why you're breaking this up into 3 parts, seems like excel VBA is an extra step that complicates it).

`thisworkbook.worksheets(1).cells(i,5)` Use full references when learning VBA

let me know if this works, I don't know enough about your situation to know exactly what you need, other than what I can see you're trying to do.

```
Sub Dan()

Dim Order As String
Dim Title As String        'initialize title
Dim Palette As String      'intialize comment
Dim Fpalette As String
Dim Frow As Integer    'initialize bottom-most row
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cntr As Integer
Dim LR As Integer
Dim wsALL As Worksheet

'Clears the contents of the last macro run
With Sheets("ALL.txt")
    .Range(.Cells(6, 2), .Cells(725, 8)).ClearContents 'equates to (D2:F26)/         row, column ;Erase Columns for next macro
End With

Title = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value
Palette = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
Frow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Set wsALL = Sheets("ALL.txt")

    i = 2

    Do While i < Frow

        i = i + 1

        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Title And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Palette Then

            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Copy Destination:=wsALL.Range("B734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'wsALL.Range("B734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 11), Cells(i, 14)).Copy Destination:=wsALL.Range("C734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'wsALL.Range("C734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 10)).Copy Destination:=wsALL.Range("G734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
           'wsALL.Range("G734").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

**Ignore the Below, I was going to make this way more complicated than necessary. Looking at your code, be sure to reference using**

Hi Joshua,

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish, adding in more details such as the first macro may help in getting you a specific answer. I think possibly VBA in Excel may not be the best way. A VBA in Access sounds possible solution. But this may be of help to you.

---

*I know you said for an end user, It would be much more complicated on your part but I've had great success using microsoft query to import data, with the correct ODBC driver "Access Database Engine" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 it works great now and I use it to get data from flat files then send it to SQL based on a query, but I fought with it to get it to work you will rip your hair out and it wouldn't be portable to an end user*

---

Having a user enter a value into a specific cell could work, i.e. put a value in A1 and VBA can check that value using:

```
Alpha = Cells(1,1).Value
pStart = Cells(2,1).Value 'A2
pEnd = pStart + 30
```

In order to prevent any issues with spaces this could be done as:

```
set pStart = Trim(ActiveCell(2,1).Value)
```

Or another way is to use data validation and give users a drop down list. https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-or-remove-a-drop-down-list-5a598f31-68f9-4db7-b65e-58bb342132f7

---

Here is the code if for either way. Notice I've made some edits, most are not essential changes, just how I write VBA. When you use the copy -> paste command it avoids the clipboard if you say `.Copy Destination:=` *Another comment, this would be so easy in Access simply write an SQL statement and use the append feature. You say that you have a macro before this, and after this, I would say make it one (very powerful and nice) SQL statement what is run through a user form.*

Comment: Thanks for the input Nathan. I'll rephrase my question in the original post.